# How is the Greek to be understood with regards to 'only' at Mark 13:32's final clause, "but only the Father"?

Tags: greek, mark

Mark 13:32's is

> "No one knows about that day or hour, not even the angels in heaven,
> nor the Son, **but only the Father**." (Berean Standard Bible)

The use of 'only' in the final clause is typical. Some add 'alone' in italics, as with the NASB.

> "But about that day or hour no one knows, not even the angels in
> heaven, nor the Son, but the Father *alone*."

Yet, the KJB doesn't include 'alone' or 'only'. It is simply

> "But of that day and that hour knoweth no man, no, not the angels which
> are in heaven, neither the Son, but the Father."

Young's Literal has it as

> "And concerning that day and the hour no one hath known -- not even
> the messengers who are in the heaven, not even the Son -- **except the
> Father**."

What can we say about the appropriateness of adding 'only' or 'alone' or 'except' here? How strongly is it motivated by the Greek text? What are arguments for or against including it?

Answer (score 1):

The text (with my overly literal translation) of Mark 13:32 is:

> Περὶ δὲ τῆς ἡμέρας ἐκείνης ἢ τῆς ὥρας οὐδεὶς οἶδεν, οὐδὲ οἱ ἄγγελοι ἐν
> οὐρανῷ οὐδὲ ὁ υἱός, εἰ μὴ ὁ πατήρ. = Now, about that day or the hour,
> no one knows, not even the angels in heaven, nor the Son, if not the
> Father.

This is quintessential Hebrew/Greek idiom that does not convey the force and sense of the writer in his phrase << οὐδὲ ... οὐδὲ ... εἰ μὴ >> = neither ... nor ...if not = "neither ... nor ... except" in this context/construction.

The effect of this (to us) awkward construction (but common and good Greek) is simply what most versions give - the final phrase can be translated as any of:

- but only the Father
- except the Father
- but the Father alone
- but the Father
- etc.

All these are required to make good English and convey the sense of what is being said.  The original is clear - no one knows except the Father alone.